# Can not run Flutter project on Windows because CMake Error

Tags: flutter, visual-studio

I want to run flutter app on windows 10, I installed Visual Studio and Android Studio, The app is working fine on mobile, but when it's running on Windows platform I faced this problem:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):

Generator

Visual Studio 16 2019

could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

Flutter doctor has not any problem:
[image]

- My Visual Studio version is 2022 which downloaded from
  https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads
- CMake had installed and added into Path env.

How Can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to instal Visual Studio 2019, because Visual Studio 2022 is/was not supported.

Comment: Why would one need Visual Studio at all for Flutter development

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ compiler is mandatory because it's needed in the build process if he is targeting the Windows platform. That's how Flutter building toolchain has been designed by Google.